# What is the difference between a.getClass() and A.class in Java?

Tags: java, class, reflection

In Java what pros/cons exist surrounding the choice to use `a.getClass()` or `A.class`? Either can be used wherever a `Class<?>` is expected, but I imagine that there would be performance or other subtle benefits to using both in different circumstances (just like there are with `Class.forName()` and `ClassLoader.loadClass()`.

Answer (score 176, accepted):

I wouldn't compare them in terms of pros/cons since they have different purposes and there's seldom a "choice" to make between the two.

- `a.getClass()` returns the **runtime type** of `a`. I.e., if you have `A a = new B();` then `a.getClass()` will return the `B` class.
- `A.class` evaluates to the `A` class **statically**, and is used for other purposes often related to reflection.

In terms of performance, there *may* be a measurable difference, but I won't say anything about it because in the end it is JVM and/or compiler dependent.

---

This post has been rewritten as an article [here](http://programming.guide/java/difference-between-class-and-getclass.html).

Comment: How about `A.class.getClass()` ?

Comment: That would give you the `Class` object of the class representing the `A.class` object which is again an instance of `java.lang.Class`.

Comment: How about `A.getClass().class`?

Comment: @ShikharMainalee, that doesn't really make sense if `A` is a class. There's no static `getClass` method on classes.

Comment: how does this relate to the suggestion [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16571046/231821) that they also point to different class loaders. This might also be a significant difference between the two?

Comment: What does SomeClass::class returns and it is different than that o SomeClass.class?

Comment: @IrfanUlHaq, `SomeClass::class` isn't valid Java code. That won't compile so it won't return anything.

Comment: @aioobe Thank you. I really thought `class` was a static variable. This clears things up.

Answer (score 35):

They are actually different with regards to where you can use them. `A.class` works at compile time while `a.getClass()` requires an instance of type `A` and works at runtime.

There may be a performance difference as well. While `A.class` can be resolved by the compiler because it knows the actual type of `A`, `a.getClass()` is a virtual method call happening at runtime.

For reference, a compiler targeting bytecode typically emits the following instructions for `Integer.getClass()`:

```
aload_1
invokevirtual   #3; //Method java/lang/Object.getClass:()Ljava/lang/Class;
```

and the following for `Integer.class`:

```
//const #3 = class  #16;    //  java/lang/Integer

ldc_w   #3; //class java/lang/Integer
```

The former would typically involve a virtual method dispatch and therefore presumably take longer time to execute. That is in the end JVM-dependent however.

Comment: [1] technically the Java Language Specification doesn't mention any constant pool at all...

Comment: @aioobe: I guess you are right, that's why I checked the bytecode generated by Sun JDK.

Comment: ...which technically speaking does not provide an authoritative answer either, since the Java Language Specification doesn't even mention bytecode when it comes to semantics.

Comment: @aioobe: I get your point. I have never mentioned JLS, just empirically checked how it works, as I wasn't sure. The OP asks about performance and examining bytecode seemed like a good idea. Feel free to edit my post or remove ambiguous statements

Comment: roll back if you don't like it ;-)

Answer (score 9):

have a look at the examples below

`a.getClass()!= A.class`, i.e. a is not an instance of A but of an anonymous sub class
of A

`a.getClass()` requires an instance of type A

Answer (score 8):

Use `a.getClass` when you have an instance of class/type and you want to get exact type of it.  while `a.class` is used when you have `type` available and you want to create instance of it. 
Also `getClass()` returns runtime type of instance while `.class` is evaluated at compile  time.
Considering performance of `getClass()` and`.class` ,`.class` has better performance than  `getClass()`  .
**Example :**

```
public class PerfomanceClass {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        long time=System.nanoTime();
        Class class1="String".getClass();
        class1="String".getClass();
        class1="String".getClass();
        class1="String".getClass();

        System.out.println("time (getClass()) :"+(System.nanoTime()-time)+" ns");     


        long time2=System.nanoTime();
        Class class2=String.class;
        class2=String.class;
        class2=String.class;
        class2=String.class;

        System.out.println("time (.class):"+(System.nanoTime()-time2)+" ns");
    }

}
```

Output :

```
time (getClass()) : 79410 ns
time (.class)     : 8032 ns
```

Answer (score 1):

There is one difference i would like to add. Let us say you have a class a constructor as shown below with a super class which takes a Class object. You want that whenever a subclass object is created the subClass' class object should be passed to the super class. Below code will not compile as you cannot call an instance method in a constructor. In that case if you replace `myObject.getClass()` with `MyClass.class`. It will run perfectly.

```
Class MyClass
{
    private MyClass myObject = new MyClass();
    public MyClass()
    {
        super(myObject.getClass()); //error line compile time error
    }
}
```

Comment: Having instance of the same class as instance variables of the same class.... You will run out of heap space as you are recursively creating objects.

Answer (score 1):

Interestingly the differences in performance mentioned in the example above, seem to be related to other reasons. Using 3 different Classes, in average the performance will be nearly the same :

```
import java.util.LinkedHashMap;
public class PerfomanceClass {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    long time = System.nanoTime();
    Class class1 = "String".getClass();
    Class class11 = "Integer".getClass();
    Class class111 = "LinkedHashMap".getClass();

    System.out.println("time (getClass()) :" + (System.nanoTime() - time) + " ns");

    long time2 = System.nanoTime();
    Class class2 = String.class;
    Class class22 = Integer.class;
    Class class222 = LinkedHashMap.class;

    System.out.println("time (.class):" + (System.nanoTime() - time2) + " ns");
} }
```

The Output will be something like :

```
time (getClass()) :23506 ns 
time (.class):23838 ns
```

And switching the order of the calls will even result in `getClass()` being faster.

```
import java.util.LinkedHashMap;

public class PerfomanceClass {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    long time2 = System.nanoTime();
    Class class2 = LinkedHashMap.class;

    System.out.println("time (.class):" + (System.nanoTime() - time2) + " ns");

    long time = System.nanoTime();
    Class class1 = "LinkedHashMap".getClass();

    System.out.println("time (getClass()) :" + (System.nanoTime() - time) + " ns");
}}
```

Output:

```
time (.class):33108 ns
time (getClass()) :6622 ns
```

Comment: "Using 3 different Classes" . But in the getClass() section you are not using 3 different classes. These are all String and therefore getClass will return java.lang.String for all instances.

Answer (score 1):

`p.getClass()`, where the `p` is an instance of an object, returns the runtime class of this object `p`. `p` cannot be a type which will cause a compile-time error, it should be an instance of an object.

```java
// B extends A
A a = new B();
System.out.println(a.getClass());
//output: class B
```

`p.class` is an expression. The `.class` is called the class syntax. `p` is a type. It can be the name of a class, interface or array and even a primitive type. 
`a.getClass() == B.class`.

If a type is available and there is an instance then it is possible to use `getClass` method to get the name of the type. Otherwise, use the `.class` syntax