# Alternative method to TextView.getMaxLines() for Android 4.0.3 (API 15) and below

Tags: android, backwards-compatibility, nosuchmethoderror

I am getting below crash logs while using `getMaxLines()` method of Texview on Ice Cream Sandwich Android 4.0.3 version,

So I got the real issue is, that my application is running lower sdk which does not have this getMaxLines() method.

How can remove this crash. I didn't find any alternatives method

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: android.widget.TextView.getMaxLines
            at com.text.mobile.new.adapters.ServiceListAdapter.onBindViewHolder(ServiceListAdapter.java:232)
            at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Adapter.onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.java:5277)
            at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Adapter.bindViewHolder(RecyclerView.java:5310)
            at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:4568)
            at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:4461)
            at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager$LayoutState.next(LinearLayoutManager.java:1962)
            at android.support.v7.widget.GridLayoutManager.layoutChunk(GridLayoutManager.java:438)
            at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.fill(LinearLayoutManager.java:1334)
            at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.onLayoutChildren(LinearLayoutManager.java:563)
            at android.support.v7.widget.GridLayoutManager.onLayoutChildren(GridLayoutManager.java:171)
            at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayout(RecyclerView.java:2847)
            at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.onLayout(RecyclerView.java:3145)
            at android.view.View.layout(View.java:11278)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4224)
            at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onLayout(RelativeLayout.java:925)
            at android.view.View.layout(View.java:11278)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4224)
            at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onLayout(RelativeLayout.java:925)
            at android.view.View.layout(View.java:11278)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4224)
            at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1628)
            at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1486)
            at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1399)
            at android.view.View.layout(View.java:11278)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4224)
            at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:431)
            at android.view.View.layout(View.java:11278)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4224)
            at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1628)
            at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1486)
            at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1399)
            at android.view.View.layout(View.java:11278)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4224)
            at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:431)
            at android.view.View.layout(View.java:11278)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4224)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1489)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.handleMessage(ViewRootImpl.java:2442)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Found something similar check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16255480/is-it-possible-to-textviewgetmaxlines-on-pre-api-16-devices

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The [getMaxLines()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/widget/TextViewCompat.html#getMaxLines(android.widget.TextView)) of  `TextViewCompat` looks like the appropriate solution for this.

You can also take a look in the [SourceCode](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_support/blob/master/v4/java/android/support/v4/widget/TextViewCompat.java) of TextViewCompat, and copy the functions you need.

**Code:**

```
int maxLines = TextViewCompat.getMaxLines(yourtextView);
```

instead of:

```
int maxLines = yourtextView.getMaxLines();
```

---

I highly recommend using the support lib and TextViewCompat.
But just for completeness, here is also the (current)  source of [TextViewCompatDonut](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_support/blob/master/v4/java/android/support/v4/widget/TextViewCompatDonut.java) 's `getMaxLines` :

```
static int getMaxLines(TextView textView) {
        if (!sMaxModeFieldFetched) {
            sMaxModeField = retrieveField("mMaxMode");
            sMaxModeFieldFetched = true;
        }
        if (sMaxModeField != null && retrieveIntFromField(sMaxModeField, textView) == LINES) {
            // If the max mode is using lines, we can grab the maximum value
            if (!sMaximumFieldFetched) {
                sMaximumField = retrieveField("mMaximum");
                sMaximumFieldFetched = true;
            }
            if (sMaximumField != null) {
                return retrieveIntFromField(sMaximumField, textView);
            }
        }
        return -1;
    }
```

Comment: Thanks very much, but my compiler did not find the getMaxLines in TextViewCompat as well ,

Comment: @LavekushAgrawal You may have to update your support lib.

Comment: I have updated the my support library as well, but still compiler didn't find the getMaxLines in TextViewAppCompact.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/97506/discussion-between-lavekush-agrawal-and-oberflansch).

Answer (score 0):

Try this,it may help,

```
      TextView t1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txt1);

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN) {
           int no= t1.getMaxLines();
            Log.e("No of Lines: ", String.valueOf(no));
        }
```