# Query on instance of Class class

Tags: java, class

Every object in Java belongs to a certain class. That's why the `Object` class, which is inherited by all other classes, defines the `getClass()`.

`getClass()` method returns the instance of `Class` class.

For example:

```
class Foo{}
class Sample{ class Foo instance = Foo(); Class obj = instance.getClass(); }
```

Another way of getting the instance of `Class` class is by saying `Foo.class`

My question:

I can see the definition of `getClass()` in `Object` class source code(File Object.java package java.lang). In which source file, can i see the member `class` which we are using as `Foo.class`?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Difference between a.getClass() and A.class?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10947768/difference-between-a-getclass-and-a-class)

Comment: This might be already answered..
(http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10947768/difference-between-a-getclass-and-a-class)

Comment: Check the other answers, and also [this from the JLS](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.8.2). the `.class` is an expression called a class literal.

Comment: @Deco So this is a syntactic stuff as per the given link of JLS. Deco, if this duplicate question?

Comment: @overexchange - not really. `.getClass()` and `.class` are used for different things. The former is used at run time, the latter is checked at compile-time. Check out the linked question and its answers.

Comment: @Deco i think i already know the difference in getting runtime/compile time type. I think, my question is not referring to this point. Can you please go thru my question again?

Comment: @Deco I did not understand the meaning of these statements from the JLS link. Can you give an example?  "It is a compile-time error if the named type is a type variable (§4.4) or a parameterized type (§4.5) or an array whose element type is a type variable or parameterized type.

It is a compile-time error if the named type does not denote a type that is accessible (§6.6) and in scope (§6.3) at the point where the class literal appears."

Comment: The named type cannot be a type variable (e.g. `T` if you have a parameterized class such as `SomeClass<T>`), parameterized type (e.g. can't have `ArrayList<String>.class`, only can have `ArrayList.class`), or an array whose element is a type variable (e.g. can't have `T[].class` in a class `SomeClass<T>`) or parameterized type (e.g. can't have `ArrayList<String>[].class`). Last two points just mean that these literals are subject to the same access/scoping rules (i.e. `private`, `protected`, etc.) that other variables are.

Comment: @user3580294 From usage perspective, we can use getClass() method in finding some third party class meta info. for example if 'Object obj' is the parameter of my method, i can get the actual type of obj by saying 'obj.getClass()', But i did not understand the necessity of Foo.class in real time.

Comment: You have to use a class literal in `instanceof` expressions, for example, as the compiler requires that the right side of the expression be a compile-time constant. It could be useful other instances too if you happen to already know the class you want, such as in the parameter for a method.

Comment: @user3580294 One last point, I did not understand this statement from Java Doc, "The primitive Java types ({@code boolean},
  {@code byte}, {@code char}, {@code short},
  {@code int}, {@code long}, {@code float}, and
  {@code double}), and the keyword {@code void} are also
  represented as {@code Class} objects."

Comment: `boolean.class`, `byte.class`, etc. are all valid class literals. To be honest, I haven't run into a case where those would be used, but I suspect that they would find a use for reflection (which I've been lucky enough to not need to use).

Comment: @user3580294 In statement, 'char ch='A';'  'A' is character literal, But i did not understand the meaning of class literal, when you say for example, boolean.class or Foo.class is class literal

Comment: A "class literal" is defined in the JLS to be "an expression consisting of the name of a class, interface, array, or primitive type, or the pseudo-type void, followed by a '.' and the token class." So `String` is a class, `Class<String>` is the class object for `String`, and `String.class` is the class literal for `Class<String>`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No source file. `class` is a keyword (like `this`, `instanceof`, etc), not a member of any class, and is handled by the compiler, not in code.

Answer (score 0):

If an instance of an object is available, then the simplest way to get its Class is to invoke `Object.getClass()`

```
Foo foo=new Foo();
Class c = foo.getClass();
```

If the type is available but there is no instance then it is possible to obtain a Class by appending `.class` to the name of the type. This is also the easiest way to obtain the Class for a primitive type.

```
boolean b;
Class c = boolean.class;
```

and this would produce compile-time error

```
Class c = b.getClass();
```

because a boolean is a primitive type and cannot be dereferenced

And for something like this

```
Foo foo=null;
```

note that you cannot use `foo.getClass()` in this case since it is not instantiated.

And finally for something like this

```
Foo foo=new FooChild();
Class c= foo.getClass(); //returns FooChild, evaluates at runtime
Class c= Foo.class;// returns Foo , evaluates statistically at compile-time.
```

Edit:- For `.class` its a static field inside every primitive type, `static Class<Integer>` ,The Class instance representing the Integer. you can see it here for [Integer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html?is-external=true)  , here for [Boolean](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Boolean.html). boolean, byte, char, short, int, long, float, and double all of them have a Class static field because like i said its always going to stay same and primitive types cannot be cannot be dereferenced. To see the source, if you see source of Integer you can see the class field as `public static final Class<Integer> TYPE = (Class<Integer>) VMClassLoader.getPrimitiveClass('I');` , see [here](http://developer.classpath.org/doc/java/lang/Integer-source.html)  line 82. You can search and see for others too.

Comment: foo.class; This is wrong. BTW the links that Mandar is pointing to already answers this, but my question is something else, I did not ask when to use getClass() and when to use class literal?

Comment: I have edited, meant Foo.class . Also updated answer to include answer to `, can i see the member class which we are using as Foo.class`