# How do you automatically pass all nested static classes into a method call as a parameter?

Tags: java, kryonet

Is there a way of retrieving an array of static classes within the `Network` class (defined below), and pass each class's attribute `class` into a parameter of a method call `kryo.register`?

```
public class Network {
    // Classes to be transferred between the client and the server
    public static class A {
        public int id;
        public String name;
    }

    public static class B {
        public int id;
        public int x;
        public int y;
    }

    // Rest of the classes are defined over here

    static public void register(EndPoint endPoint) {
        Kryo kryo = endPoint.getKryo();

        // typical way of registering classes so that kryonet can use it
        // kryo.register(A.class);
        // kryo.register(B.class);
        // the rest of the classes are registered with kryonet over here

        // my attempt at solving the question,
        // but for some reason this doesn't work?
        for(Object o : Network.class.getDeclaredClasses()) {
            kryo.register(o.getClass());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I found the reason why the code above doesn't work: [What is the difference between a.getClass() and A.class in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10947768/what-is-the-difference-between-a-getclass-and-a-class-in-java). I guess I need to use reflection somehow?

Comment: Use this, for (Class<?> c : Network.class.getDeclaredClasses())

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are using the class of the class, which isn't what you want.  if you used the correct type for the result of the `getDeclaredClasses()` call, it would have been more obvious:

```
    for(Class<?> c : Network.class.getDeclaredClasses()) {
        kryo.register(c);
    }
```

(btw, you are already using reflection -> `getDeclaredClasses()`).